# Canvas vanishes after touching the screen

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm trying to create an android app for playing connect four.
My problem here is whenever I touch the screen, my connect four grid vanishes and instead, the dot that I'm supposed to drop just appears at the bottom of screen. I'm not able to identify the problem with my code. The canvas just bluntly vanishes and the dot I'm supposed to drop doesn't go in the place it's supposed to go.

Main Activity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(new CFGrid(this));
        }
    }
```

Connect four class:

```
    public class CFGrid extends View{

        private Paint paint = new Paint();
        private Paint red = new Paint();
        private Paint blue = new Paint();
        public CFGrid(Context context)
        {
            super(context);
            setWillNotDraw(false);
        }
        int w , h , cx = 0 , cy = 0 , i , j , c , p = 0;
        boolean game = false;
        int sx , sy;
        int[] count={6,6,6,6,6,6,6};
        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
        {
            float X = event.getX();
            float Y = event.getY();
            c = (int) Math.floor( 7 * X / w);
            c = Math.abs(c);
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {   if(X < = ( 40 + sx ) || Y < = ( 40 + sy ) )
                   {
                       game=true;
                       invalidate();
                   }

            }
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            canvas.drawColor(Color.YELLOW);
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            w = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
            h = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
            sx = w / 14;
            sy = h / 16;
            for(i = sx ;  i < w && cx < 7 ; i = i + ( w/7 ) , cx++)
            {      cy = 0;
                for (j =  sy ; j < h && cy <6 ; j = j + ( h/8 ), cy++)
                {
                    canvas.drawCircle(i , j , 50 , paint);
                }
            }
            red.setColor(Color.RED);
            blue.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            if(game) {
                if (p == 0) {
                    canvas.drawCircle(sx + c * w / 7, sy + count[c] * h / 8, 50, red);
                    count[c] = count[c] - 1;
                    p = 1;
                } else if (p == 1) {
                    canvas.drawCircle(sx + c * w / 7, sy + count[c] * h / 8, 50 , blue);
                    count[c] = count[c] - 1;
                    p = 0;
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I don't mean to sound rude, but does your space bar work? It's very hard to read things like `for(i=sx;i<w&&cx<7;i=i+(w/7),cx++)`. I suggest you reformat the code to match the default style (or at least post it using the default style here, doesn't matter what you use in your computer). Also, it's absolutely unclear how you're using this, you'll need to post a little bit more code to know how your view hierarchy is. You're setting the content directly to a View (`setContentView(new CFGrid(this));` this makes it hard to debug.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for replying! I reformatted the code. I'm new here and didn't know about the formatting and thus posted my code in bad fashion. Thanks for correcting me. Also, what extra details do you need about me using the code? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Thanks for updating it, I don't have time to look at it right now, but I'll peek at it later. I think you don't need `setWillNotDraw(false)` because you're a View, not a ViewGroup.